# S3 and Web Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-s3, storage, media

I am making an app that uses S3 to store a lot of user media which I then display to the user at a later time. I am trying to figure out the best and most secure way to accomplish this.

I read that storing the media at S3 and then using the url from S3 to load media might be a bad choice because it can expose information that you might not want out in the open. Is it right to download all media to the sever from S3 before loading it on a page? that seems like it defeats the purpose of S3 in the first place if I have to keep downloading media from there in order to display it.

What is the best practice for accomplishing this?

I would appreciate a little advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Security by Obscurity (that is, hoping that people don't find some information) isn't a good form of security. Your system should be designed to be secure, regardless of what information people know (eg the folder structure of your documents). Serving content via a Signed URL will guarantee security of the files even if somebody knows the storage structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to use S3. There isn't a single "best-practice".

**Serve all content through web server:**

In this scenario, S3 is used simply as a storage medium. Content is requested through the web server, which then downloads the content from S3 and forwards the contents to the client.

In this scenario, the client is not aware of the S3 bucket.

This does not defeat the purpose of S3 because the purpose of S3 (in this scenario) is content storage, not delivery.

**Serve content from a public S3 bucket:**

In this scenario, you setup your S3 bucket to serve up the content directly. In this case, all of the content is public, so direct linking to the content from the web app is used. All content in the S3 bucket can be downloaded by anyone.

The bucket can be referenced as bucket.s3-website.amazonaws.com, or under your own domain.

This scenario has the benefit that it offloads the delivery of the content from your web server.

**Serve content from a private S3 bucket:**

In this scenario, your bucket is private, but you still serve up the content directly. Using this system, you create expiring pre-signed URLs to protect the private content. The content is downloaded directly from S3, but not all content can be downloaded by everyone.

Like the previous scenario, this scenario has the benefit that it offloads the delivery of the content from your web server.

**CloudFront:**

You can use CloudFront in front of your app and/or S3 buckets to do any of the following:

1. cache the content, speeding up global delivery,
2. protect your web server, in conjunction with WAF

**Final thoughts:**

The setup you choose depends on your application.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. One of my biggest concerns with the public bucket is the ability to simply right click on the media have access to the url which might contain structure that is best not to be made public. If I were to use the pre-signedURL, would that help that or is CloudFront the only way to create a more masked url?

Comment: Presigned urls won't mask the structure. CloudFront may mask some of the structure. Using your own server can fully mask it.

Comment: in a setting where you are using your own server to mask the structure, how would that work?

Comment: There's no single answer. Generally your code would get the file from s3, wherever it is.